# Red Hat 8.6 ISO with kickstart file

Tags: rhel, iso

I'm trying to understand on whether there's a difference in the final customized ISO with kickstart file of RHEL 8.6, as created through the solution given by RedHat on this forum (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/60959), versus using the mkksiso tool from the Lorax package.